# Issue with Admob Interstitial Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've followed Google Admob [step by step tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial) on implementing Interstitial Ad on my 3D Unity game, but the interstitial didn't shown when running the game on my device.

Do you know what's wrong in my code, and how to fix it?

**Ad Script**:

```
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    static int loadCount = 0;

    bool GameHasEnded = false;
    float RestartDelay = 1.5f;


    private void Start()
    {

        #if UNITY_ANDROID
           string appId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        #else
           string appId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);

        this.RequestInterstitial();

        if ((loadCount % 3) == 0)  // only show ad every third time
        {
            if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
            {
                this.interstitial.Show();
            }
        }
    }

    void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().path);
        loadCount = loadCount + 1;
    }

    private void RequestInterstitial()
    {
       #if UNITY_ANDROID
           string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
       #else
           string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
       #endif

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem seems to happen because the interstitial ad takes a while to load (sometimes up to 3 seconds). You're trying to call it too fast, and it's not loaded, so nothing happens. What I did was continually try to show the interstitial ad in void Update until it shows (using a bool called shown):

```
void Update () {
     if (shown == false) {
         ShowInterstitial();
     }
}
public void ShowInterstitial()
{
     if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
     {
         interstitial.Show();
         shown = true;
     } else    {
         Debug.Log ("Interstitial is not ready yet.");
     }    
}
```

You could also load the ad at the beginning of the level, and then only call it when the round is over.

Comment: I called the ShowInterstitial function when the player lose and before restarting the scene, and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to initalize admob and request new interstitial on every restart. You have to create one instance of AdmobController or whatever and use it.

```
public class AdManager{

   public static AdManager instance;

   private void Awake(){
       if(instance == null) {
         instance = this;
         DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
       } else {
         Destroy(gameObject);
         return;
       }
   }


   private void Start()
   {


       #if UNITY_ANDROID
          string appId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
       #else
          string appId = "unexpected_platform";
       #endif

       // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
       MobileAds.Initialize(appId);

       this.RequestInterstitial();

   }

    public void showInterstitial(){
      if ((loadCount % 3) == 0)  // only show ad every third time
      {
        if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            this.interstitial.Show();
        }
     }

}
```

then when you want to show interstitial

```
AdController.instance.showInterstitial();
```

It may have syntax error or something but you've get the idea.